# Google custom search results page don't show any results

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to use the google custom search in a wordpress website (but without any plugin).

I've used the code google provided (the search box code and the search results page code) and the results page it's returning empty...

However the auto-complete it's working:

[image]

This is the page that should show the results: http://www.guiasdeviagens.com/pesquisa/

Anyone could help me please? I've been trying for some days and can't fix the problem. :(

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By some chance did you turn on search engine blocking? Go to the admin dashboard and look at the top of the page for "Search Engines Blocked". If it's there, click on it and toggle the Site Visibility setting. Remember that once you are visible you still want to [submit your URL to google](http://www.google.com/addurl/?continue=/addurl). It also helps to have a [sitemap.xml](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-sitemap-generator/) file to help the googlebot find all of your pages.